# Import Requests not working in GCP python Function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am new to using GCP Cloud Functions and I am trying to deploy a Cloud Function using Python, that when called it will perform a get request and return some data. To do that I am using the requests.get() function of the *Requests* module. When calling the function I get the following error:

> NameError: name 'requests' is not defined

After updating the code to include *import requests* in the main.py file and calling the function I get the error:

> import requests
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

I then tried to include it in the requirements.txt file as

> requests==2.*

and received the 'no module' error. Below is the code I'm trying to run.

```
def web_request (requests):
data = requests.get_json()
if data['parameter'] == 'input':
  GET_request = requests.get('RequestURL')
  GET_data = GetRequest.json()
return GET_data
```

Please advise on the best resolution.

Comment: You will need to do three steps (a) download the `requests` package using e.g. `requirements.txt` and then `pip import`; (b) `import` the package in your code; (c) use it in code by referencing it (you're doing this). For Cloud Functions (I think) you must use `requirements.txt` so that the builder knows how to do (a) although IIRC there are some libraries (perhaps `requests`) that are assumed to be used.

Comment: Here's a [tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-requests/) for using `requests`.

Comment: Here's a [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/create-deploy-http-python) for deploying a Python Cloud Function

Comment: Here's the list of [pre-installed packages](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-python). Somewhat confusingly (since they're pre-installed), it appears you must still reference the package in `requirements.txt`

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example that mirrors your code (see caveats below)

`requirements.txt`:

```
functions-framework==3.*
requests==2.*
```

`main.py`:

```py
import functions_framework
import requests


@functions_framework.http
def web_request (request):
    # request -- is the parameter
    data = request.get_json()
    if data['parameter'] == 'input':
        # requests -- is the imported package
        response = requests.get(data['url'])
        data = response.json()
        return data
```

> **NOTE** The above code is a reflection of yours. It contains no error-handling.

###### Create local Python environment

```bash
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate

python3 -m pip install requirement=requirements.txt
```

###### Run the Cloud Function locally

In one shell, start the server:

```bash
functions-framework --target web_request
```

In another shell, test the server:

```bash
curl 
--request POST \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data '{"parameter":"input","url":"http://ip.jsontest.com/"}' \
http://localhost:8080/web_request
```

Should yield something like:

```
{"ip":"11.22.33.44"}
```

###### Deploy the Cloud Function to Google Cloud

```bash
BILLING=[YOUR-BILLING]
PROJECT=[YOUR-PROJECT]
REGION=[YOUR-REGION]

gcloud projects create ${PROJECT}
gcloud beta billing projects link ${PROJECT} \
--billing-account=${BILLING}

# Deploy
gcloud functions deploy web_request \
--runtime=python310 \
--trigger-http \
--allow-unauthenticated \
--region=${REGION} \
--project=${PROJECT}

# Test
gcloud functions call web_request \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--region=${REGION} \
--data='{"parameter":"input","url":"http://ip.jsontest.com/"}'
```

Yields e.g.:

```
{"ip":"2600:1900:2000:13::14"}
```

Or:

```bash
TOKEN=$(\
  gcloud auth print-identity-token)
ENDPOINT=$(\
  gcloud functions describe web_request \
  --region=${REGION} \
  --project=${PROJECT} \
  --format="value(httpsTrigger.url)")

curl --request POST \
--header "Authorization:bearer ${TOKEN}" \
--header "Content-Type:application/json" \
--data '{"parameter":"input","url":"http://ip.jsontest.com/"}' \
${ENDPOINT}
```

Comment: Thanks @DazWilkin, Ive modeled the requirements.txt like you showed above. When adding the 'import requests' to the main.py file, that's where I see the `import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'`. I was a little confused by the section after you NOTE. Is that something I include in the code file or is there somewhere that needs to be executed? thanks.

Comment: So, if you want to run the code locally you'll need to do two things: (a) install the packages; (b) use `functions-framework` to run your code. The command `python3 -m pip install requirement requirements.txt` does (a) and you can then `functions-framework --target web-request` to run your code. When you deploy the function to Cloud Functions, the service does (a) and (b) for you.

Comment: Locally it works great, the issue I’m having is once deployed to Cloud Functions. The errors from the originally post were pulled from logs in The GCP console. I’m at a loss, adding ‘import request’ fails to deploy but including it I get an error when calling the function saying requests isn’t defined.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. If you follow the instructions in my answer, the Cloud Function will deploy correctly. The logs **will** include the historical data because you're using the same project, region, function name etc. You should disregard earlier logs and focus on the logs that originate from the timeframe when the function deploys successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Second Generation Google Cloud Functions, when fail, sometimes give misleading error messages. I had a similar problem with the import requests, but in the end it was a malformed string. I found the issue when I deployed as 1st Gen and after the fix it worked on 2nd Gen as well. Running locally as shown by [@DazWilkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/609290/dazwilkin) helps a lot avoiding this kind of problem.

In your case your variable is shadowing the requests package. You should re-write your function to use the name `request` for your parameter instead of `requests`.

The first line of your code will be:
`def web_request (request):`

The rest of code likely needs fixing as well, but this should take care of the error you are getting.